# Check a specific row and column in mysql from vb.net

Tags: mysql, vb.net

```
Using conn As New MySqlConnection("server=localhost;user=root;password=;database=dbrentalsystem")
        conn.Open()
        Dim commandReader As New MySqlCommand("select * from tbl_unit", conn)
        Dim reader As MySqlDataReader = commandReader.ExecuteReader
        While reader.Read
            If reader.IsDBNull(2) Then
                lblUnit1.Text = "Vacant"
            Else
                lblUnit1.Text = "Occupied"
            End If
        End While
        commandReader.Dispose()
        reader.Close()
        con.Close()
    End Using
```

Here's my code, I just want to check if there is data in **column 2, row 3**

Comment: This is a database, not a spreadsheet. If the question you want answered is what's in column 2 row 3, then you may need to examine if your processes are using the database correctly. But anyways, a column is searched using its column name, the row is located by a columnName=value where clause. That's about all that can be said without knowing the table schema

Comment: You may want to spend some time with a basic SQL Tutorial.  If you want specific things, dont use `SELECT *`.  `SELECT COL2 FROM tblUnit WHERE SomeThing = foo` .

Comment: In relational databases, there is **no such thing** as "row 3". Results are "sets" or "relations", and the formal definition says they are _unordered_. You might get a certain one order the first time you query the table, but database is perfectly free to give you a different order the next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A fast and somewhat dirty approach is add a count and count to 3 in the reader.. This is bar far not the best solution to the task, but it will work :)

```
Using conn As New MySqlConnection("server=localhost;user=root;password=;database=dbrentalsystem")
    conn.Open()
    Dim commandReader As New MySqlCommand("select * from tbl_unit", conn)
    Dim reader As MySqlDataReader = commandReader.ExecuteReader
    Dim i as integer = 1
    While reader.Read
        if i = 3 then
           If reader.IsDBNull(2) Then
               lblUnit1.Text = "Vacant"
           Else
               lblUnit1.Text = "Occupied"
           End If
        end if
    i += 1
    End While
    commandReader.Dispose()
    reader.Close()
    con.Close()
End Using
```